# Validate one-to-many model.parent is not self

Tags: python, django

Assuming I have the following model:

```
class Queue(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=False)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True,
                              related_name='children')
```

What's the best way to make sure that a Queue is never its own parent? What I'm doing now is checking things in the model's `clean()` method:

```
class Queue(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=False)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True,
                              related_name='children')

    def clean(self):
        if self.id is not None:
            if self.id == self.parent_id:
                raise ValidationError('Queues cannot be their own parent.')
```

Is that the best/correct way to do things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean):

> a model’s `clean()` method is not invoked when you call your model’s
>   `save()` method.

...which is to say that it has to be called manually and does not run every time an object is modified.

If you are using a `ModelForm` or editing the object from the Django admin, then the form handling code will call the `clean()` method as part of the form validation.

However, if your code is manipulating these objects directly (not through a `Form`) and then saving them, the `clean()` method will not be called and your constraint will not be enforced. You need to ensure that you manually call [`Model.full_clean()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.full_clean) before saving objects:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
try:
    queue.full_clean()
    queue.save()
except ValidationError as e:
    # Constraints are not met - don't save the object
```

PS: as far as `ModelForm` validation goes, implementing the `clean()` method is exactly the right approach.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @solarissmoke. So `clean()` is the right way and I'll want to be mindful of calling `full_clean()` whenever manually handling things?

Comment: Yes, that should ensure your constraints are always enforced.